# jQuery .remove(); with delay not working

Tags: jquery, button, delay, removeclass

I have a reset button which set back the value of the input (type=text). this works great but I want, that the buttons "submitbtn" and "resetbtn" disappear after 2 seconds.
the buttons are added with .after behind the "input" tag.

```
.after("<button class='submitbtn' type='submit' value='Update'>Update</button><button class='resetbtn' type='reset' value='Reset'>Reset</button>");
```

With this code the "set back" job of the reset button does not work, but the buttons disappear.

```
$("button.submitbtn, button.resetbtn").click( function()
           {
             $last.nextAll("button.submitbtn, button.resetbtn").remove();
           }
);
```

What can I do, that the reset-button works and all buttons disapears after 2 seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use settimeout
will execute code block after milisecond what u set

```
setTimeout(function(){
//code here
}, miliseconds);
```

for u code to buttons dissapear after 2 sec, u can do it by that way

```
$("button.submitbtn, button.resetbtn").click( function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  $last.nextAll("button.submitbtn, button.resetbtn").remove();
 },2000);
);
```